# Dimension of the sum of multiple subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be finite dimensional and $U_1,U_2,...,U_m$ are subspaces of $V$. Assume the sum $U_1+U_2+...+U_m$ is not direct. I am trying to understand the form of the general formula for $dim(U_1+U_2+...+U_m)$.

**My try:**

Without loss of generality assume $m$ is even. Then using associativity of the sum:

$$dim(U_1+U_2+...+U_m) = dim( (U_1+...+U_{m/2}) + (U_{m/2+1}+...+U_{m}) )$$

Hence, using the formula for the dimension of the sum of two subspaces
$$ dim(U_1+U_2) = dim(U_1)+dim(U_2)-dim(U_1 \cap U_2) $$

We can rewrite:
$$dim(U_1+U_2+...+U_m) = dim(U_1+...+U_{m/2}) + dim(U_{m/2+1}+...+U_{m}) - dim((U_1+...+U_{m/2}) \cap (U_{m/2+1}+...+U_{m})) $$

Then continue splitting recursively:

$$dim(U_1+U_2+...+U_m) = \sum_{i} dim(U_i) - \sum_{i=2k} dim(U_{i-1} \cap U_i) - \sum_{i=4k} dim((U_{i-3}+U_{i-2})\cap((U_{i-1}+U_{i})) - ... - dim((U_1+...+U_{m/2})\cap(U_{m/2+1}+...+U_{m}))
$$
With $k\geq 1$